# How to best represent a 2-D array in a database?

Tags: arrays, database, database-design, database-schema

I am looking for a good solution to represent a 2-D array in a database. With a few catches of course. For instance, the array could grow in terms of columns and rows (which could be inserted at any point). Also important is that people (users) can manipulate specific cells in this array (and hopefully without having to update the entire array). Also there may be multiple arrays to store.

I have thought about using a json  but that would require always writing the entire json to database when an update is made on a a specific cell which would not be idea especially when multiple people could manipulate the array at once.

Answer (score 1):

The typical data structure would be three columns:

- row
- column
- value

Of course, you might have other columns if you have a separate array for each user (say a `userid` or `arrayid` column).  Or, you might have multiple values for each cell.

Comment: yeah but how would one link those all together to represent an array

Comment: @user1009698 . . . The table is the array.

Comment: ok maybe i didnt make it clearer, there can be multiple arrays. So i cant have a table per array when there could be hundreds

Comment: You can map a 2D array to represent rows and columns. Row = Index / ColumnWidth. Column = Index % ColumnWidth.

Comment: @user1009698 . . . Then read the part of the answer that says you can have separate arrays, if you include other columns identifying the arrays.